# Jersey Json List<List<Entity>> serialize

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I have following problem:

I have a json-rest service written in Java. I want to return an entity wich includes a list. This list includes also a list. When i call the rest-service i get the first element right, but from the other only the id.

Can anyone help me?

Here are some code-snippets:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property = "@Entity")
public class Entity {

    private Long id;

    private List<List<Parent>> possibleParents = new ArrayList<List<Parent>>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<List<Parent>> getPossibleParents() {
        return possibleParents;
    }

    public void setPossibleParents(List<List<Parent>> possibleParents) {
        this.possibleParents = possibleParents;
    }

}


@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property = "@Parent")
public class Parent {

    private Long id;

    private String parentType;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getParentType() {
        return parentType;
    }

    public void setParentType(String parentType) {
        this.parentType = parentType;
    }
}
```

Here's the service:

```
@Path("/get")
public class EntityRestService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Entity get() {
        Entity e = getFilledEntity();
        return e;
    }

}
```

And here is what i get:

```
{
   "@Entity": "ef0ecdbf-c354-4646-8ef0-d4794b3e7919",
   "id": "1",
   "possibleParents": [
    [{ "@Parent": "easecdbf-c354-4646-8ef0-d4794b3e7919",
       "id": "1", "parentType": "Test"
        }, 
        "5c0c708e-0c23-4432-954f-20f42909067f", 
        "a2a644d4-3068-4662-b95a-d313d896b17f"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Expected:

```
{ "@Entity": "ef0ecdbf-c354-4646-8ef0-d4794b3e7919", 
  "id": "1", 
  "possibleParents": [ 
     [{"@Parent": "easecdbf-c354-4646-8ef0-d4794b3e7919",
        "id": "1", "parentType": "Test" }, 
      {"@Parent": "5c0c708e-0c23-4432-954f-20f42909067f",
       "id": "2", "parentType": "Test2" }, 
      {"@Parent": "a2a644d4-3068-4662-b95a-d313d896b17f",,
       "id": "3", "parentType": "Test3" } 
     ] 
   ] 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your showing us all the code or if its the right code considering possibleParents should be the property and not parents. My guess is your parents list is a heterogeneous list of objects. Put a debug break point or log out he contents of the parent list in the controller.

Comment: There are more than one possible parents combination. So I could have two lists of parents in the possibleParents list.

Comment: We found that the Jackson serializer does not handle certain structures, so we started using Gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: I have to think about that. But I'm in hope that anybody has a solution for my problem.

Comment: Seems that this object has been already serialized before. Is thera a possibility to say wirte the whole object not only the id?

Comment: Can you share your `ObjectMapper` configuration? I serialized your structure with default `ObjectMapper` and the output is as you expected.